# Watir finds elements by class, but elements are null?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I am able to find elements by class using Watir, but I can't figure out how to do additional processing with them after selection - the elements found are nil (see below).

I would love to see the html text of each element found.

[image: code fragment]

Answer (score 1):

You have instances of `Watir::HTMLElement` which at time of definition only stores the parent and selector. The `@element` variable which represents the object in the DOM located by Selenium through a browser driver will only be populated when you take an action on the element.

To see the text of each element, just put `puts event.text` inside your loop.